What jobs do you recommend to improve my English?
I’m a freelance software developer living in USA, and I need to improve my English fluency and speaking confidence as soon as possible.
So, I decided to find a part-time job that will encourage me to talk to people.
I’m wondering what kind of jobs you’d recommend that could help me improve my English in a calm, peaceful environment—one that doesn’t make people mad at me :)
P.S. I'm looking for a relaxed and friendly environment where people aren't in a rush, and if I don’t fully understand what they're saying, it’s not a big deal.

Depending on where you live, you might be near a small shop or cafe that has a more relaxed environment. I'm thinking something where people are often happy when they go there and not in a rush. Maybe something that aligns with your interests? Other options - if you like children, maybe a preschool or daycare. If you like elderly people, a nursing home or assisted care center. A public library might be another good place to look.

If you don't need more income, then you might have a better time asking a place if you can volunteer with them and being honest about your goals. Childcare centers, nursing homes, libraries, etc. are always looking for more community volunteers! If you were volunteering, then everyone would be more patient with you and no one would get upset if you didn't understand right away or took longer to respond to a question.
But, if you also want more income, then there are plenty of jobs that could suit you too

I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for employment recommendations.

Libraries and librarians and schools will expose you to standard English.

try toastmasters

When I lived abroad, I worked as a barista and a bartender. In my first job, I often found myself having the same or a similar short conversation with many different people, and the repetition helped me perfect "small talk." I stopped searching for words as I spoke, and I was able to focus more on pronunciation. One day, I responded to someone I didn't know with a short phrase that I had practiced many times, and they were surprised to find out I was not a native speaker.
At another bar, I got to know the patrons and my conversations with them became more in depth. Because we knew each other, I wasn't as embarrassed to make mistakes and that helped me gain more confidence in speaking.
You might have a similar experience with the same jobs in the United States. They aren't that difficult to come by these days, but you might not earn a ton of money!
I also tried a retail job, but that wasn't really my thing.
